# Change Active Navigation Image on Page Scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm attempting to reproduce a similar navigation bar to what's used on this website: http://www.julisudi.com/ . The main effect I'm looking for is to have each image become active when the correct anchor is reached on the page.

I have seen this done with text via http://jsfiddle.net/Vandeplas/up4nu/150/ I have also created some images and use the following CSS to reproduce the 'change colour' effect when the image becomes active:

```
#mainmenu a img {
     position: relative;
     margin-bottom: -30px;
     margin-top: 5px;
}

#mainmenu a img:hover, #mainmenu a img.active{ 
     top: -31px;
}
```

The problem I'm having is replacing code in the jfiddle to make it work with images rather than text. If anyone could help that would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `id` on any elements, it can be a `<p>` or an `<img>` .

In the menu, it doesn't matter if `<a>` is filled with text , `img` or both.

http://jsfiddle.net/up4nu/2682/

Comment: I get the idea, but can't see to get it working with my code. Here's a  cut down version of it: http://jsfiddle.net/WSc66/ . The hover effect works, but the images don't get the active clas applied to them.

Comment: @user3477755 you did not load the jQuery framework and did not write correctly you selector. class active is set on li, not img  update of your fiddle :  http://jsfiddle.net/WSc66/1/

Comment: Thanks that's perfect! I was starting to think the .active should be on li after looking at other examples, but I didn't know .active could be placed in the middle of a selector.

Now to get it working with my website, on jsfiddle it works with 'onload' but not with in<head> which is the issue I'm having now.

Comment: i guess it has to do with CSS selector, and , oups, yes , i forgot, in your script you look for href in a tags , not img tags ...

Comment: in the jsfiddle it works fine, on my website I still can't get it working. Grr so close!

Comment: Fixed! Had to add window.onload = function () {}; round the script. Thanks for the help!